# OL3 Custom proj/resolutions and minZoom/maxZoom

Tags: openlayers-3, epsg

Is the use of ol.view minZoom and maxZomm in addition to resolutions in a non webmercator map OK? Are minZoom and maxZoom really ignored? Or can they cause troubles?

I have behaviour that I can't figure out. Here is my issue:

I use a WMTS service (EPSG:2154) as basemap in a ol3 map (EPSG:2154 too).
I set both View resolutions and ol.tilegrid.WMTS resolutions with:

```
var resolutions = [305.748084412797, 152.87417449832975, 76.43695495723364, 38.21860977054807, 19.109304885274035, 9.554652442637018, 4.777326221318509, 2.3886631106592544, 1.1943315553296272, 0.5971657776648136, 0.2984505969011562, 0.13229193125051253 ];
```

and use matrixids in the ol.tilegrid.WMTS

```
var matrixids= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10 ,11];
```

The map is OK 12 zoom levels are available. Basemap matrix ids are consistent with map zoom level.

But trying to limit the zoom levels I set 'minZoom' and 'maxZoom' in the view options in addition to 'resolutions'.

If minZoom = 0 and maxZoom = 8, I still can zoom over the 12 levels and map zooms are consistent with the basemap tilematrix called.

If minZoom = 4 and maxZoom = 9, I can zoom over 12 levels... but

- Map zoom level starts at 4 and goes up to 15 (the shift from initial zoom levels = minZoom set in ol.View)
- The basemap tilematrix are now unconsistent with map zoom: at map zoom 4 it requests basemap zoom level 0 (no shift applied to basemap calls)

thanks !

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a living example (jsfiddle or a working code snippet would be nice)

Comment: here is a fiddle, just uncomment the minzoom maxzoom to see the diffrences. https://jsfiddle.net/4emke5c1/1/

Comment: Still not perfect, but you can add custom behaviour to the event `map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(e) {});`
I have edited your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4emke5c1/2/

Comment: yes i think this is the kind of workaround i should try. According to OL3 doc setting ol.view resolutions should make minzoom and maxzoom ignored ... no ? i wonder if i should log this as a bug ?

Comment: Icarus : could you turn your comment into answer ? since I ill use this workaround I can flog it as the answer to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since minZoom and maxZoom make problems with resolutions, I would recommend you to add custom behavior to the event "change:resolution" as follows:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(e) {
    // Set Zoom
});
```

I have edited your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4emke5c1/2)

Comment: Zoom Button and MouseWheel Zoom have different behavior regarding map center so in order to force max and min zoom at 'change:resolution' i needed to get map center et set it again. If not it makes pan.